# Groupby values in 2nd column, pick value in 1st column and plot values [against that first column value] from each of remaining (three) columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

Right off the bat I want to apologize if I did not follow any formatting rules.

My raw data looks like the following:

```
{'SOC_percent\tTemp_degC\tmeasuredResistance_discharge_mOhm_2s\tmeasuredResistance_discharge_mOhm_10s\tmeasuredResistance_discharge_mOhm_30s': {0: '5\t-30\t10.41234227\t17.87211262\t39.78919418', 1: '5\t-25\t9.005372364\t14.65298748\t31.43701839', 2: '5\t-20\t7.00477665\t11.96754116\t24.39672451', 3: '5\t-10\t4.76738317\t8.501801895\t16.57636139', 4: '5\t0\t3.287172099\t5.57923204\t9.111447624', 5: '5\t5\t2.284002209\t4.236576914\t6.727561459', 6: '5\t10\t1.869262009\t3.249023803\t5.020990525', 7: '5\t20\t1.27797832\t1.963468963\t2.881752003', 8: '5\t25\t0.936303318\t1.546113511\t2.21395074', 9: '5\t35\t0.707298817\t1.091719664\t1.630883462', 10: '5\t45\t0.543718996\t0.787786805\t1.224869972', 11: '5\t50\t0.479637917\t0.674293305\t1.068590803', 12: '10\t-30\t8.537862111\t13.76174563\t27.78918201', 13: '10\t-25\t6.685843592\t10.49706991\t20.26777709', 14: '10\t-20\t5.09106992\t7.978204366\t14.64512627', 15: '10\t-10\t3.139438794\t4.984757272\t8.55042102', 16: '10\t0\t1.991892456\t2.847802776\t4.272164584', 17: '10\t5\t1.509715963\t2.222798386\t3.332446494', 18: '10\t10\t1.21478403\t1.750446842\t2.62220956', 19: '10\t20\t0.804205279\t1.112408203\t1.663905423', 20: '10\t25\t0.632856291\t0.897095496\t1.340630939', 21: '10\t35\t0.526353672\t0.71202232\t1.078469491', 22: '10\t45\t0.442828733\t0.573468612\t0.879484805', 23: '10\t50\t0.407810006\t0.517250198\t0.797987409', 24: '15\t-30\t6.417216981\t9.928443396\t19.83665094', 25: '15\t-25\t5.204660377\t7.83495283\t15.09165094', 26: '15\t-20\t4.063358491\t6.200141509\t11.37070755', 27: '15\t-10\t2.622933962\t4.123330189\t7.229716981', 28: '15\t0\t1.767141509\t2.592150943\t3.923669811', 29: '15\t5\t1.334830189\t2.047745283\t3.042', 30: '15\t10\t1.103283019\t1.625367925\t2.386603774', 31: '15\t20\t0.764179245\t1.049566038\t1.513518868', 32: '15\t25\t0.616150943\t0.8775\t1.240150943', 33: '15\t35\t0.500009434\t0.702981132\t1.006518868', 34: '15\t45\t0.423358491\t0.57690566\t0.826358491', 35: '15\t50\t0.397910377\t0.51754717\t0.759028302', 36: '20\t-30\t4.841886792\t6.89245283\t12.58301887', 37: '20\t-25\t3.826783019\t5.370471698\t9.450754717', 38: '20\t-20\t3.027037736\t4.226226415\t7.066603774', 39: '20\t-10\t1.916518868\t2.734415094\t4.374622642', 40: '20\t0\t1.298650943\t1.716490566\t2.423150943', 41: '20\t5\t1.032518868\t1.411235849\t1.96704717', 42: '20\t10\t0.867198113\t1.152584906\t1.612735849', 43: '20\t20\t0.614556604\t0.78159434\t1.103896226', 44: '20\t25\t0.526622642\t0.691698113\t0.953169811', 45: '20\t35\t0.435009434\t0.597509434\t0.822556604', 46: '20\t45\t0.3835\t0.522943396\t0.706783019', 47: '20\t50\t0.373075472\t0.475849057\t0.66704717', 48: '25\t-30\t3.597688679\t4.51259434\t6.929858491', 49: '25\t-25\t2.749377358\t3.451745283\t5.085330189', 50: '25\t-20\t2.223735849\t2.706084906\t3.755896226', 51: '25\t-10\t1.369537736\t1.676632075\t2.206320755', 52: '25\t0\t0.940537736\t1.05545283\t1.290556604', 53: '25\t5\t0.797660377\t0.934160377\t1.155773585', 54: '25\t10\t0.686301887\t0.796311321\t1.028962264', 55: '25\t20\t0.501726415\t0.574943396\t0.792386792', 56: '25\t25\t0.461622642\t0.55495283\t0.739773585', 57: '25\t35\t0.382273585\t0.522698113\t0.687650943', 58: '25\t45\t0.349773585\t0.487377358\t0.617867925', 59: '25\t50\t0.353759434\t0.446415094\t0.59959434', 60: '30\t-30\t2.64306337\t2.770057921\t4.983524437', 61: '30\t-25\t2.086447367\t2.250982857\t4.314656224', 62: '30\t-20\t1.727334342\t1.854598294\t3.523595931', 63: '30\t-10\t1.165635292\t1.26288389\t1.583111294', 64: '30\t0\t0.831038221\t0.929507256\t1.153892595', 65: '30\t5\t0.743804417\t0.822642168\t1.020970617', 66: '30\t10\t0.639777679\t0.731319903\t0.907245747', 67: '30\t20\t0.480690569\t0.58496518\t0.725098507', 68: '30\t25\t0.43765325\t0.526189514\t0.651881429', 69: '30\t35\t0.400254942\t0.48262454\t0.611746277', 70: '30\t45\t0.368114597\t0.445089067\t0.576382366', 71: '30\t50\t0.353712659\t0.428235255\t0.560248926', 72: '35\t-30\t2.597669811\t2.713136792\t3.087745283', 73: '35\t-25\t2.044617925\t2.206014151\t2.537575472', 74: '35\t-20\t1.691103774\t1.808778302\t2.069207547', 75: '35\t-10\t1.144858491\t1.233957547\t1.57545283', 76: '35\t0\t0.805448113\t0.910122642\t1.114504717', 77: '35\t5\t0.728674528\t0.806490566\t0.983891509', 78: '35\t10\t0.633504717\t0.709603774\t0.882773585', 79: '35\t20\t0.472783019\t0.576292453\t0.710462264', 80: '35\t25\t0.433691038\t0.517485849\t0.635466981', 81: '35\t35\t0.397174528\t0.473948113\t0.602292453', 82: '35\t45\t0.369028302\t0.441570755\t0.571570755', 83: '35\t50\t0.354771226\t0.425964623\t0.557681604', 84: '40\t-30\t2.556584906\t2.660707547\t2.924632075', 85: '40\t-25\t2.006292453\t2.164622642\t2.403896226', 86: '40\t-20\t1.660443396\t1.771066038\t1.950245283', 87: '40\t-10\t1.127075472\t1.210349057\t1.530688679', 88: '40\t0\t0.784292453\t0.888660377\t1.081084906', 89: '40\t5\t0.717943396\t0.789933962\t0.955377358', 90: '40\t10\t0.62645283\t0.694886792\t0.861311321', 91: '40\t20\t0.466650943\t0.56954717\t0.696971698', 92: '40\t25\t0.431698113\t0.512273585\t0.623509434', 93: '40\t35\t0.395641509\t0.469349057\t0.594933962', 94: '40\t45\t0.368415094\t0.438198113\t0.567584906', 95: '40\t50\t0.354311321\t0.422745283\t0.555075472', 96: '45\t-30\t2.51795283\t2.612570755\t2.78604717', 97: '45\t-25\t1.972259434\t2.127523585\t2.288613208', 98: '45\t-20\t1.633462264\t1.737646226\t1.84354717', 99: '45\t-10\t1.111745283\t1.189806604\t1.498188679', 100: '45\t0\t0.767429245\t0.872103774\t1.053183962', 101: '45\t5\t0.709051887\t0.777056604\t0.93115566', 102: '45\t10\t0.621240566\t0.682622642\t0.843528302', 103: '45\t20\t0.461745283\t0.564028302\t0.685933962', 104: '45\t25\t0.430257075\t0.507674528\t0.613391509', 105: '45\t35\t0.394476415\t0.465363208\t0.588801887', 106: '45\t45\t0.36804717\t0.435438679\t0.564212264', 107: '45\t50\t0.354035377\t0.42007783\t0.552775943', 108: '50\t-30\t2.487324752\t2.571003179\t2.624742662', 109: '50\t-25\t1.941874744\t2.091626265\t2.198386641', 110: '50\t-20\t1.614132861\t1.717907652\t1.86246071', 111: '50\t-10\t1.101742804\t1.179615538\t1.34124724', 112: '50\t0\t0.755056968\t0.842862796\t1.030306432', 113: '50\t5\t0.707658681\t0.757797046\t0.921586561', 114: '50\t10\t0.61064567\t0.683998956\t0.82747666', 115: '50\t20\t0.461607921\t0.56313721\t0.674500603', 116: '50\t25\t0.431767087\t0.51355881\t0.612027845', 117: '50\t35\t0.395653787\t0.469831833\t0.585359573', 118: '50\t45\t0.364559062\t0.432224387\t0.5614416', 119: '50\t50\t0.350606411\t0.415369189\t0.550384704', 120: '55\t-30\t2.44804717\t2.529174528\t2.582462264', 121: '55\t-25\t1.917070755\t2.06620283\t2.113235849', 122: '55\t-20\t1.590537736\t1.683683962\t1.666943396', 123: '55\t-10\t1.088443396\t1.157919811\t1.469981132', 124: '55\t0\t0.746580189\t0.853707547\t1.013938679', 125: '55\t5\t0.696787736\t0.762339623\t0.895589623', 126: '55\t10\t0.616334906\t0.66545283\t0.819', 127: '55\t20\t0.455613208\t0.556669811\t0.671216981', 128: '55\t25\t0.42903066\t0.500316038\t0.598674528', 129: '55\t35\t0.39325\t0.459231132\t0.580216981', 130: '55\t45\t0.36804717\t0.431759434\t0.559306604', 131: '55\t50\t0.354035377\t0.416398585\t0.549096698', 132: '60\t-30\t2.416773585\t2.493915094\t2.517462264', 133: '60\t-25\t1.895915094\t2.041981132\t2.053141509', 134: '60\t-20\t1.57459434\t1.663141509\t1.597037736', 135: '60\t-10\t1.080471698\t1.146575472\t1.474273585', 136: '60\t0\t0.74259434\t0.851867925\t1.00259434', 137: '60\t5\t0.693415094\t0.7605\t0.884245283', 138: '60\t10\t0.616641509\t0.66054717\t0.812254717', 139: '60\t20\t0.454386792\t0.554830189\t0.667537736', 140: '60\t25\t0.429245283\t0.497556604\t0.594075472', 141: '60\t35\t0.393188679\t0.457084906\t0.577764151', 142: '60\t45\t0.368415094\t0.430839623\t0.557773585', 143: '60\t50\t0.354311321\t0.415386792\t0.547716981', 144: '65\t-30\t2.38795283\t2.462948113\t2.476990566', 145: '65\t-25\t1.879051887\t2.022051887\t2.011443396', 146: '65\t-20\t1.562330189\t1.646891509\t1.539396226', 147: '65\t-10\t1.07495283\t1.13829717\t1.490830189', 148: '65\t0\t0.742900943\t0.854933962\t0.996768868', 149: '65\t5\t0.691882075\t0.762339623\t0.877193396', 150: '65\t10\t0.618787736\t0.65809434\t0.809188679', 151: '65\t20\t0.454386792\t0.554216981\t0.666311321', 152: '65\t25\t0.430011792\t0.495410377\t0.591316038', 153: '65\t35\t0.393495283\t0.455551887\t0.576537736', 154: '65\t45\t0.369028302\t0.430533019\t0.556853774', 155: '65\t50\t0.354771226\t0.414926887\t0.546643868', 156: '70\t-30\t2.361584906\t2.436273585\t2.46104717', 157: '70\t-25\t1.866481132\t2.006415094\t1.988141509', 158: '70\t-20\t1.553745283\t1.634933962\t1.494018868', 159: '70\t-10\t1.071886792\t1.133084906\t1.519650943', 160: '70\t0\t0.7475\t0.86290566\t0.996462264', 161: '70\t5\t0.692188679\t0.767858491\t0.874433962', 162: '70\t10\t0.622773585\t0.65809434\t0.809801887', 163: '70\t20\t0.455613208\t0.554830189\t0.667537736', 164: '70\t25\t0.431330189\t0.493877358\t0.590396226', 165: '70\t35\t0.394169811\t0.454632075\t0.576537736', 166: '70\t45\t0.369886792\t0.430839623\t0.55654717', 167: '70\t50\t0.355415094\t0.415018868\t0.545877358', 168: '75\t-30\t2.337669811\t2.413891509\t2.469632075', 169: '75\t-25\t1.85820283\t1.995070755\t1.983235849', 170: '75\t-20\t1.548839623\t1.627268868\t1.46090566', 171: '75\t-10\t1.071273585\t1.130938679\t1.360735849', 172: '75\t0\t0.756391509\t0.875783019\t1.001674528', 173: '75\t5\t0.694334906\t0.777056604\t0.875966981', 174: '75\t10\t0.628599057\t0.66054717\t0.81409434', 175: '75\t20\t0.458066038\t0.556669811\t0.671216981', 176: '75\t25\t0.433200472\t0.492957547\t0.591316038', 177: '75\t35\t0.395212264\t0.454325472\t0.577764151', 178: '75\t45\t0.370990566\t0.431759434\t0.556853774', 179: '75\t50\t0.356242925\t0.415662736\t0.545417453', 180: '80\t-30\t2.316207547\t2.395801887\t2.502745283', 181: '80\t-25\t1.854216981\t1.988018868\t1.996726415', 182: '80\t-20\t1.547613208\t1.623896226\t1.440056604', 183: '80\t-10\t1.073113208\t1.131858491\t1.314084906', 184: '80\t0\t0.769575472\t0.893566038\t1.01240566', 185: '80\t5\t0.698320755\t0.789933962\t0.881792453', 186: '80\t10\t0.636264151\t0.66545283\t0.822066038', 187: '80\t20\t0.461745283\t0.559735849\t0.677349057', 188: '80\t25\t0.435622642\t0.492650943\t0.594075472', 189: '80\t35\t0.396622642\t0.454632075\t0.580216981', 190: '80\t45\t0.372339623\t0.433292453\t0.557773585', 191: '80\t50\t0.357254717\t0.416858491\t0.545264151', 192: '85\t-30\t2.297198113\t2.382004717\t2.560386792', 193: '85\t-25\t1.854523585\t1.985259434\t2.028613208', 194: '85\t-20\t1.550066038\t1.624816038\t1.431471698', 195: '85\t-10\t1.07740566\t1.13584434\t1.379698113', 196: '85\t0\t0.787051887\t0.916254717\t1.02865566', 197: '85\t5\t0.704146226\t0.806490566\t0.891910377', 198: '85\t10\t0.645768868\t0.672811321\t0.833716981', 199: '85\t20\t0.466650943\t0.564028302\t0.685933962', 200: '85\t25\t0.438596698\t0.492957547\t0.598674528', 201: '85\t35\t0.398400943\t0.455551887\t0.583896226', 202: '85\t45\t0.373933962\t0.435438679\t0.559306604', 203: '85\t50\t0.358450472\t0.418606132\t0.545417453', 204: '90\t-30\t2.29946844\t2.383584796\t2.489622642', 205: '90\t-25\t1.86032786\t1.974433564\t2.103911344', 206: '90\t-20\t1.566292427\t1.657804525\t1.4556559', 207: '90\t-10\t1.096469402\t1.168700917\t1.315493648', 208: '90\t0\t0.809138285\t0.89081257\t1.0451439', 209: '90\t5\t0.727080727\t0.796859124\t0.93661049', 210: '90\t10\t0.63385084\t0.715685937\t0.842639129', 211: '90\t20\t0.488533958\t0.583686013\t0.689454905', 212: '90\t25\t0.446604847\t0.529868037\t0.626826454', 213: '90\t35\t0.404214431\t0.478697896\t0.591510491', 214: '90\t45\t0.368150895\t0.435245215\t0.56020084', 215: '90\t50\t0.35210775\t0.415939509\t0.54586218', 216: '95\t-30\t2.266537736\t2.367287736\t2.549254717', 217: '95\t-25\t1.868014151\t1.992617925\t2.147575472', 218: '95\t-20\t1.566009434\t1.639533019\t1.45109434', 219: '95\t-10\t1.093349057\t1.153014151\t1.447716981', 220: '95\t0\t0.834882075\t0.976349057\t1.077712264', 221: '95\t5\t0.721316038\t0.850641509\t0.925023585', 222: '95\t10\t0.67029717\t0.694886792\t0.868056604', 223: '95\t20\t0.480141509\t0.576292453\t0.710462264', 224: '95\t25\t0.446200472\t0.495410377\t0.613391509', 225: '95\t35\t0.403061321\t0.459231132\t0.594933962', 226: '95\t45\t0.377858491\t0.441570755\t0.564212264', 227: '95\t50\t0.361393868\t0.423757075\t0.546643868', 228: '100\t-30\t2.254886792\t2.366367925\t2.580481132', 229: '100\t-25\t1.881198113\t2.002735849\t2.234650943', 230: '100\t-20\t1.5795\t1.653330189\t1.479301887', 231: '100\t-10\t1.105\t1.166198113\t1.450122642', 232: '100\t0\t0.865235849\t1.013754717\t1.110518868', 233: '100\t5\t0.732660377\t0.878235849\t0.948018868', 234: '100\t10\t0.685320755\t0.709603774\t0.890745283', 235: '100\t20\t0.488726415\t0.584264151\t0.72640566', 236: '100\t25\t0.450830189\t0.497556604\t0.623509434', 237: '100\t35\t0.405943396\t0.461990566\t0.602292453', 238: '100\t45\t0.380188679\t0.445556604\t0.567584906', 239: '100\t50\t0.363141509\t0.427160377\t0.547716981'}}
```

I want the following plot from this raw data (x axis = 2s, 10s and 30s; y axis = resistance data). The raw data doesn't contain any numeric information for time_seconds.
[image: Required final plot]

I was able to achieve this via MS Excel 2016, using pivot tables and tables. It took a while but I was able to build a template. Then I came across some plots people have uploaded to the internet using Pandas and Seaborn, which got me thinking about reducing the time and effort it took to build the excel template. I don't have anything higher than seaborn 0.8.1 and I don't think I will be able to upgrade to anything higher than that version.

My questions are: 1) is it possible to develop something similar in Python 3.6 and Pandas such that I can get a similar looking plot as the one above? 2) If yes, how would I go about accomplishing this (knowing that the raw data doesn't contain values for time (in seconds)?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! First of all, don't post your df as images, but give us an easy way to replicate it. Posting it as text, or posting your `df.to_dict()` are usually nice ways to do it

Comment: Ok .. wasn't aware of that. One second while I generate that. Are there any other edits that I need to make in the question?

Comment: No, I think this is it ;) All the rest is in line with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [mcve]. Bear these in mind whenever you post, i'll help you get better/faster answers !

Comment: Cool :) thanks - I just pasted the output of df.to_dict() - let me know if the "minimal reproducible example" requirements were satisfied

Comment: You don't need to dump the whole dataset here. Few lines (around 10) are usually enough. People can understand, and the question is a lot more readable. Also, the format you used is a bit hard to read or import if we want to try our code. I suggest to write the data to a file: use `df.to_csv('filename.csv')` and copy-paste in the question the first 10 or so lines of `'filename.csv'`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, indeed you can do this with `pandas` and `matplotlib`. Consider for example the following function:

```
def myplotting(dt, SOC_p, temp):
    """plot data at selected SOC_percent and temperature.

    dt: the dataframe
    SOC_p: a list of 'SOC_percent' values. A line for each percentage will be plotted.
    temp: numeric, a single temperature value.
    """
    x = [2, 10, 30]
    selplt = dt.loc[(dt['SOC_percent'].isin(SOC_p)) & (dt['Temp_degC'] == temp)].drop('Temp_degC', axis=1).set_index('SOC_percent')
    for prc in SOC_p:
        plt.plot(x, selplt.loc[prc], label=f'SOC percent: {prc:d}')
    plt.title(f'Temp_degC: {temp:d}')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Discharge Resistance (mOhm)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

The function works with your dataframe. You need to give it as argument your dataframe, a list of `'SOC_percent'` values and a temperature value.
First the relevant row at the requested temperature and percentage values are selected using `loc`. Then, the plot is produced with a `for` loop (a line for each percentage value). Finally, title, label and legend are added.

For example, to reproduce your plot, you do:

```
myplotting(df, [10, 20, 30], -10)
```

where `df` is your dataframe. The following plot will be produced:

[image]